# Events functionality should apply on all pages in datagridview - Paging concept

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a task to develop Windows applications where paging is involved. If I perform any event like splitting date and time, it's applied only to the current page. I would like to apply that event to all pages in the `Datagridview`.

If I take a `datatable/dataset` and work on it, the UI is taking time to read the file as it again reads the whole file to data table. So, please suggest  any other alternative to apply the events to all pages in the `DataGridView`.

I will post the code, or upload my code in any site or here, if required.
Please let me know if my question is unclear.

**VARIABLES DECLARATION:**

```
List<String> cmbList = new List<string>();
        public String Replace;
        public String Find;
        public String Col;
        public String NewColumn;
        public String NewColumnValue;
        public string MyFOrmat { get; set; }
        int PageCount;
        int maxRec;
        int pageSize = 30;
        int currentPage = 1;
        int recNo = 0;
        string FileName;
        String[] datfile;
```

**button1 = BROWSE BUTTON (Where i read the file):**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "Desktop";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "dat files (*.DAT)|*.DAT|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FileName);
                    datfile = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    //Added on 2015-12-02
                    maxRec = datfile.Length - 1;
                    PageCount = maxRec / pageSize;
                    LoadPage(MyFOrmat);
 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

**LOADPAGE Code:**

```
public void LoadPage(string Format, bool isFindAndReplace = false)
        {
            int startRec;
            int endRec;

            if (currentPage == PageCount)
            {
                endRec = maxRec;
            }
            else
            {
                endRec = pageSize * currentPage;
            }

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            if (recNo == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
            }

            int rowindex = 0;
            startRec = recNo;
            for (int RowCount = startRec; RowCount <= endRec; RowCount++)
            {
                if (datfile[RowCount].ToString() != "" )
                {
                    if (RowCount == 0)
                    {
                        string[] column = datfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                        for (int i = 0; i < column.Length - 1; i++)
                        {


     if (column[i].ToString() != "" && column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                                {
                                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvtxtcountry = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                                    dgvtxtcountry.HeaderText = column[i].ToString();
                                    dgvtxtcountry.Name = column[i].ToString();
                                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvtxtcountry);
                                    cmbList.Add(column[i]);
                                    i += 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (RowCount != 0)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                            string[] column = datfile[RowCount].Split('þ');
                            int index = 0;
                            for (int i = 1; i < column.Length - 1; i++)
                            {
                                if (column[i].ToString() != "\u0014")
                                {
                                    if (i == 3)
                                    {
                                        dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]).ToString(Format);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    { dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = column[i].Trim('þ'); }
    index += 1;
                                    i += 1;
                                }
                            }
                            rowindex += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    recNo += 1;
                }
            }
```

**FIND and REPLACE Event:**

```
 private void btnFindandReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.cmbColumnCombo.DataSource = cmbList;
            f.ShowDialog();

            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[index].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(column[i]).ToString(Format);
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().ToLower().Replace(f.txtfind.Text.ToLower(), f.txtreplace.Text);
                    //bulidDataRow(i);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.txtfind.Text))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text);
                        #region Commented
                        //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[f.cmbColumnCombo.Text].Value.ToString().Replace(f.txtfind.Text, f.txtreplace.Text);
                        //bulidDataRow(i);
                        #endregion
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentPage += 1;
        if (currentPage > PageCount)
        {
            currentPage = PageCount;
            //Check if you are already at the last page.
            if (recNo == maxRec)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You are at the Last Page!");
                return;
            }
        }
        LoadPage(MyFOrmat);
    }
```

Please let me know if anything needs to be added.

Comment: It depends how you did the implementation of the splitting, so I'm afraid we need to see your code :-)

Comment: Actually i'm reading the file into array and splitting it with separator. variable[0] is the Header part and [Variable [0],[Variable [1] and so on are values. I'm struggling on how to make events applicable to all pages in the datagridview.

Comment: Thanks for checking into it. Shall i upload the somewhere or shall i post the code here only as it's little big.

Comment: You can post it in your question. For some guidance please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially to the part for a minimal and complete code example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also: Can you explain what a 'Page' of a DataGridView is supposed to mean? Are you talking about scrolling or do you have several DGVs or what???

Comment: I posted the code in the question. Please let me know if anything needs to be added. As i mentioned, Find and Replace is working for only first page. If i click next the rest records are loading but the FIND and REPLACE logic didn't work. I will add my Next button code as well in the question.

Comment: So you create pages by loading only a range of rows? You could load all and make only those on the current page visible.

Comment: Yeah but my requirement is to break the file into chunks. In future i may get a file which has 25,000 lines also. So in that case, i will change the page size to 1000 so i will get 10 pages. When i do any event, it should applicable to all pages.

Comment: Well, either cache the data or the actions, whatever those events are doing..! Also: 25k lines is not really that much today, imo, but add 1-2 0 and the problem gets real.. You can always do the same find&replace for the cached data chunks.

Comment: Not exactly 25k but i may get till 300,000. I didn't get you exactly. Can you please tell me one more time.

Comment: If you don't mind may i know whether i conveyed my requirement in clear or shall i re frame it?

Comment: The requirements are unclear wrt what the 'events' you mention are actually doing? Change the data? Filter it? Events as such will work on the whole DGV, but if you are modifying only the present rows these modifications must either be repeated when loading other orws or be applied to all data in the first place..

Comment: Events means FIND and REPLACE, MERGING 2 columns and SPLITTING DATE & TIME columns.
When i click on any of these events (button), the functionality is applying only on the first page but i want it to apply on all pages.
Please let me know if anything required.

Comment: OK. Will those things happen more than once in more than one ways, ie will several c&r operations occur or more than always the same two columns be merged? If so I would definitely go for: Read in all lines in a datastructure; apply all those changes to the whole data structure; display pages from there when either scrolling or a change occurs.. - Will you also save it and if so where?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize your requirements:

- You want to read largish data files of 10k - 500k records
- You want to display them in chunks/pages in a `DataGridView`
- You want allow the user to modify the data:

  - The user can **merge** columns
  - The user can use **change&replace** on the data
  - Date&time columns may be **split**
- Possibly modified data shall be saved

The way I see it you have **two approaches**:

- Either **cache the data**
- Or **cache the actions**

**Caching the actions** is doable but clearly a lot more fuss, both in coding the caching and in keeping the data synchronized.

So **caching the data** would be my first choice.

Here is a sketch of how to break up the functionality:

- A function to read in the whole data and load them into a `DataTable`
- Functions for the initial display and for displaying a certain page
- Functions for doing each of the changes on the list of rows.

After calling a changing function the current page display must be refreshed.

Keeping the total quantity of data in memory shouldn't really be a problem today; I notice that you are reading in all data as strings already in the `datFile` array. Reading it into a table will spare you to split it over and over..

A `DataTable.DataRow` also offers nice properies like `HasErrors` or `RowState`. And its `Items` can have a dedicated type to help with formatting..

Note however that `DataRow` doesn't have a (real) constructor; instead it must be created from a `DataTable`, so you will first have to create one from your columns!

The display code would use a `pageSize` and a `currentFirstLine` variable; it can clear and add the rows into the DGV or you could go for a binding solution with the `DataTable` you need anyway holding the `DataRows` and a  filter on the table or rather on an `BindingSource`.

Of course you can also use a structure of your own, maybe a simple as a `string[]` or a `List<string>`to hold the row data..

If you are interested in the idea of caching the actions, you could create a `ChangeAction` class that holds:

- the type
- the parameters needed, ie, the column(s), the change&replace strings etc..

Then in a `List<ChangeAction>` you would store them as they happen and then apply them to each unchanged row. **But** here comes the first catch: You will need to know which row have been changed and maybe if a `ChangeAction` can be applied twice without screwing up the data.. More problems may or may not come later, depending on the details of you data and actions..

Here is an example of how to set up the binding using class level variables:

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();
BindingSource BS = new BindingSource();
int pageSize = 0;
int firstLineVisible = 0;
```

After filling the table you can bind it and set the initial filer:

```
BS.DataSource = DT;
dataGridView1.DataSource = BS;

pageSize = (dataGridView1.ClientSize.Height - dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight) 
          / dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height;
int l1 = firstLineVisible; int l2 = firstLineVisible + pageSize;
BS.Filter = "Nr >= " + l1  + " and Nr < " + l2;
```

When scrolling you simply change the `firstLineVisible` and rest the `Filter` **and** the `DataSource`..

Now all your data modifications should work on the data in the `DataTable` using the `SetField` method!

Also note that you need one column in your data that holds a running number. If your data don't have one it is easy to include it by adding it to the data lines:

The column gets autogenerated in the `DataGridView`. For the `DataTable` we want to have it in the first data line; I use a separator string `sep`:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList();
..
string[] sep = { ";" };
var p0 = ("Nr" + sep[0] + lines[0]).Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None );
DT.Columns.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < p0.Length; i++) DT.Columns.Add(p0[i], typeof(string));
```

Adding it to the data is just as simple:

```
for (int l = 1; l < lines.Count; l++)
{
    var p = (l + sep[0] + lines[l]).Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    DT.Rows.Add(p);
}
```

You can hide the number column if you want to..:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Nr"].Visible = false;
```

You should add that line right after setting the `Filter`.